# jQuery Drag And Drop Using Live Events with .live()

Tags: jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I am new to jquery. Here is my code

```
  // let the gallery items be draggable
        $("li", $gallery).draggable({
            cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
            revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            containment: "document",
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move"
        });

        // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
        $trash.droppable({
            accept: "#gallery > li",
            activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                deleteImage(ui.draggable);
            }
        });
```

I want to make both of these events live. Please help me how can I declare these events in terms of .live. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you mean with make them `live`, live event is not longer used in jquery... `on` is use now

Comment: Well. How I write these events using .on()? Actually I want that whenever I dynamically added list items, DOM apply drag/drop properties on these items newly added.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/